# How to extract the dataframe that includes the median and its 95% confidence interval in the survfit function?

Tags: r, dataframe, survival-analysis

Let's say I applied survival analysis on the following df

```
# Load necessary packages
library(survival)

# Generate example survival data (time to event and event status)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
time <- rexp(n, rate = 0.1)  # Exponential survival times (you can replace this with your own dataset)
status <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)  # Censoring status (0: censored, 1: event)

# Create a survival object
surv_object <- Surv(time, status)

# Fit Kaplan-Meier survival curve
km_fit <- survfit(surv_object ~ 1)
```

the output of km_fit is as follows

```
Call: survfit(formula = surv_object ~ 1)

       n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,] 100     52   14.6    10.7    17.3
```

However the data frame that includes the median and its confidence interval, I am not able to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the print method for objects of class `survfit` calls the `survmean()` function (which is not exported from the `survival` package namespace).  You can call it directly with `survival:::survmean()`.  In this case, if you step through the `survival:::print.survfit()` function using `debug`, you'll find that it sets the `rmean` argument to `"none"`.  Here's how you could get the matrix you're looking for:

```r
library(survival)

# Generate example survival data (time to event and event status)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
time <- rexp(n, rate = 0.1)  # Exponential survival times (you can replace this with your own dataset)
status <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)  # Censoring status (0: censored, 1: event)

# Create a survival object
surv_object <- Surv(time, status)

# Fit Kaplan-Meier survival curve
km_fit <- survfit(surv_object ~ 1)

km_fit
#> Call: survfit(formula = surv_object ~ 1)
#> 
#>        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
#> [1,] 100     52   14.6    10.7    17.3

survival:::survmean(km_fit, rmean="none")$matrix
#>   records     n.max   n.start    events    median   0.95LCL   0.95UCL 
#> 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000  52.00000  14.63301  10.67213  17.31154
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>